# Spring mvc checkboxes tag : not sure what is the format of path attr

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, checkbox

I am using Spring form checkbox tag. My modelAttribute is bookmarkMapping which in turn contains a list of folderMapping objects based on which I am trying to build checkboxes.

folderMapping object has property isMapping which decides the checked property of checkbox.

I am trying this

```
<form:checkboxes items="${bookmarkMapping.folderMapping}" path="isMapped"  itemValue="isMapped" itemLabel="folderName" />
```

But it keeps saying isMapped is not a property of bookMarkMapping which is true. But in what way should I give the path attribute so that it can point to a property withing bookmarkMapping.folderMapping list.

Please help.

Comment: Can you post the entire form and your controller?

Answer (score 1):

There are two lists involved in the form:checkboxes tag: the list of selected items, and the list available items to select.

The list of selected items is stored in the `path` attribute. The `path` attribute points to a array or collection of Strings in the **model**.

The `items` attribute points to the list of available items. This list is an attribute in the **request**. It is usually an Array or a List of Strings representing the labels.

Here is some sample code. The CheckboxesModel contains a List of selectedItems. The request contains the List of availableItems.

Model

> public class CheckboxesModel {
>         List selectedItems;
>
> public List getSelectedItems() { return selectedItems;  }
>
> public void setSelectedItems(List selectedItems) {
>         this.selectedItems = selectedItems;     }
>
> }

Controller

> @RequestMapping("/index.do")
>
> public String showCheckboxes(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
>
> ```
>   CheckboxesModel checkboxesModel = new CheckboxesModel();
>   List<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
>   checkboxesModel.setSelectedItems(selectedItems);
>   model.addAttribute("checkboxesModel",checkboxesModel);
>
>   List<String> availableItems = new ArrayList<String>();
>   availableItems.add("One");
>   availableItems.add("Two");
>   availableItems.add("Three");
>   request.setAttribute("availableItems",availableItems);
>
>   return "index";
> ```
>
> }

View

```
<form:form action="checkBoxes.do" commandName="checkBoxesModel" method="POST">
    <form:checkboxes items="${availableItems}" path="selectedItems"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You talked about property named isMapping but you set in the path attribute: isMapped #confused

The path is relative to the modelAttribute. You don't have isMapped property in bookmarkMapping but you have a folderMapping property.

So your path should be folderMapping.isMapped