# Spring MVC checkbox tag not posting changes made

Tags: spring, data-binding, spring-mvc

I have trouble using spring mvc checkbox tag. I have a BookmarkMapping object which in turn has List object. Inside Folder Mapping there are three attributes like id, name and isMapped (boolean). It is this isMapped property based on which I intend to show the checkbox.

So in my page I get modelAttribute as 'bookmarkMapping'. inside which there is a list of folderMapping. Each of the item inside folderMapping is isMapped set as true or false for my checkbox checked attribute.

I am trying this

```
<c:forEach var="folderMapping" items="${bookmarkMapping.folderMapping}" varStatus="i">
    <form:checkbox path="folderMapping[${i.count-1}].isMapped" label="${folderMapping.folderName}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

This displays the checkboxes fine in html but when posted it is nor reflecting changes of checkboxes as true /false in posted objects. It always shows false.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `<form:checkboxes />` tag? I think this is what you need here, maybe could solve your problem. Try something like this, replacing your `<c:forEach />` tag:

```
<form:checkboxes path="folderMapping" items="${allCheckboxValues}" itemLabel="folderName" itemValue="isMapped"/>
```

You need to prepopulate `allCheckboxValues` in your controller with all possible values.

Check out [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-checkboxestag) about this tag for more help and the [TLD documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.checkboxes).

Comment: are you using `path="folderMapping.isMapped"` ? Should work, because is the same path you used in your `form:checkbox`. The same for itemLabel.

Comment: but there in checkbox case, I have a <c:forEach> with var as folder mapping...that's why it works there

Comment: You're right. Put in your path the property name of the field mapping the list in your command object and try with these itemValue/itemLabel: `path="propertyMappingTheList" itemLabel="folderName" itemValue="isMapped"`

Comment: doing that checks the checked box for all entries present and not according ti isMapped property...

Comment: with this, checkboxes will be checked automatically if the object has the property mapping set to true. Could you post your model with all related properties?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'd noticed you have a similar answer in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14188975/787375

Answer (score 0):

Set the value attribute of the `checkbox` tag.

```
<c:forEach var="folderMapping" items="${bookmarkMapping.folderMapping}" varStatus="i">
    <form:checkbox path="folderMapping[${i.count-1}].isMapped" 
         value = "${folderMapping[${i.count-1}].isMapped}" 
         label="${folderMapping.folderName}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: it says     "${folderMapping[${i.count-1}].isMapped}" contains invalid expression(s)"